# How can i pass a date variable instead of typing dates... in JFreeChart Api

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to implement Jfreechart API and I am m facing issue:

This is my code

```
/**Adding data in this series**/
seriesOne.add(new Task("Project Progress Bar",
new SimpleTimePeriod(makeDate(25, Calendar.JUNE, 2013),
makeDate(30, Calendar.JUNE, 2013))));

/**adding second task**/
/**Adding data in this series**/
seriesTwo.add(new Task("Project Progress Bar",
new SimpleTimePeriod(makeDate(28, Calendar.JUNE, 2013),
makeDate(30, Calendar.JUNE, 2013))));
```

method of makeDate

```
private static Date makeDate(final int day, final int month, final int year) {

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);
final Date result = calendar.getTime();
return result;

}
```

I need to pass as `d1="2011-03-06" d2="2011-05-06" d3="2011-05-06" d4="2011-05-06"`
instead of harcoding the dates how can i do like this below

```
new SimpleTimePeriod(makeDate(d1),
  makeDate(d2))));
```

Thanks any help will be appreciated very much Please

Answer (score 1):

```
//assuming dates are passed in as a string in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"

public Date makeDate(String date){
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(string);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but how can i assign for four variables see above my edited code please

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use: Date d1 = makeDate("2011-03-06"); Date d2= makeDate("2011-05-06"); and so on? Can't see the benefit of what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi thanks but im using collections add method default inside it so im using that to generate image of two tasks so how can i change that elaborately pls help me from above code

Answer (score 0):

use DateFormat to get the work done hope this helps ??

```
Date d=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).parse("June 13, 2013");
```

Comment: Hi thanks but im assigning four dates variable see my above edited question and code thanks a lot